# How to serialize form, but instead of an input's values get the input's ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, serialization

Here is a [jsfiddle for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/4xuvtx9v/2/).

I need to serialize a form, so when a user hits submit I get all the ID's of the inputs the user has selected in a "serialized" format. I have used this to get the form ID's:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("div").text($("form").serialize());
});
```

The problem is, it gives me the form's values. How do I modify this code to give me the IDs of the selected inputs instead of the values?

This is the HTML:

```
<form action="">
  Choose one:<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name" id="option1" value="2.00">Option 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name" id="option2" value="2.00">Option 2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name" id="option3" value="2.00">Option 3<br>
</form>

<button>Serialize form</button>

<div></div>
```

So for example, when the button is clicked, the serialized output should say either "option1" "option2" or "option3", not "2.00" "2.00" or "2.00".

**Edit**
I was hoping there was a way to incorporate ".attr('id')" into the serialization, I have

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('change', function () {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

This alerts me the ID's, but I cannot find a way to incorporate it into the serialization.

Comment: Look at this, maybe it's an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584541/serialize-all-ids-in-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: Create a custom function for it, i will try to make one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of implementation using **Array.from**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').bind('submit', function () {
        var serialize = Array.from($('input:checked'), e => "id=" + e.id).join('&');
        console.log(serialize);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="form">
    Choose one:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="option1" value="2.00">Option 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="option2" value="2.00">Option 2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="name" id="option3" value="2.00">Option 3<br>
<br/>
    Choose one:<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name1" id="option1" value="2.00">Option 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name2" id="option2" value="2.00">Option 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name3" id="option3" value="2.00">Option 3<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Serialize form" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This function gives a the value of ID instead of name, hope this is what you needed.

Snippet has two forms one with radio and other with check boxes

```js
function getSerialize(form)
{
 var selected = $('form input:checked');
 var serialized = '';
 selected.each(function(){
  if(serialized != '')serialized += '&';
  serialized += $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).attr('id');
 });
 return serialized;
}

$('#button1').click(function(){
console.log(getSerialize('#form1'));
});

$('#button2').click(function(){
console.log(getSerialize('#form2'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>For radio</h5>
<form  id="form1"  action="">
  Choose one:<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name" id="option1" value="2.00">Option 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name" id="option2" value="2.00">Option 2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name" id="option3" value="2.00">Option 3<br>
</form>
<br>
<button id="button1">Serialize form</button>
<br>
<h5>For checkboxes</h5>

<form id="form2" action="">
  Choose one:<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name1" id="option1" value="2.00">Option 1<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name2" id="option2" value="2.00">Option 2<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name3" id="option3" value="2.00">Option 3<br>
</form>

<button id="button2">Serialize form</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, is there a way to make this work for radio inputs _and_ checkboxes?

Comment: Yes anything is possible, let me try

Comment: K check my edited answer, which has both radio and checkboxes

Comment: Works great! Exactly what I needed, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Welcome happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Classical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You don't need another serialization method. You just have to put your `option1`, `option2` and `option3` into `value` attributes, instead of `id`. This way the usual serialization will return to you what you desire.

Comment: No, the value is reserved for something else

Answer (score 0):

If the answer from Styx didn't satifies your needs then think you'll have to come up with your own "serialization". The one from jQuery is meant to serialize the data in a manner much like if you where to hit submit on a form.. When you hit submit in html, only the selected values of a radiobutton are sent.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to incorporate ".attr('id')" into the serialization, is this not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

A "*dirty*" way that works in your case is the following. But if you use it like that you are not dynamic in any way. I just get the `id` and the `name` and add it together as `string` (not `urlencoded` or anything else in this example though...).

**Please read the following for a practical solution:**

However you could place those radios **outside** the form. When someone submits the form you use `preventDefault()` to stop submission and instead append the radio id to the `serialized` form data. An example would be `serialized_data += "&name=" + encodeURIComponent(THE_ID);`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
     var radio = $('input[name="name"]:checked');
      $("div").text(radio.prop('name') + '=' + radio.prop('id'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  Choose one:<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name" id="option1" value="2.00">Option 1<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name" id="option2" value="2.00">Option 2<br>
  <input type="radio" name="name" id="option3" value="2.00">Option 3<br>
</form>

<button>Serialize form</button>

<div></div>
```

Comment: I am trying this out right now, but what do you mean by "_not dynamic in any way_"?

Comment: Well if your form has more inputs etc. that need to be serialized, it is not possible with this exact setup. Because we select a specific radio element and not "any". Therefore you should try the solution I wrote in the second section of my answer.

Comment: Also, is there a way to make this work for checkboxes too?

Comment: Sure, you can apply **most** of the code for any input element.

Comment: My apologies, but how do I incorporate the code of your second answer? What would the jQuery look like?

Comment: I am sorry but I won't provide code writing. You should try yourself to understand whats going on and get a little practice ;-). However I'd suggest you have a look at the documentation of `preventDefault()`. It is really not hard, I bet you can get it working ;-)